# How can I compress my js/css files in TYPO3

Tags: php, javascript, css, typo3, typoscript

how can I compress (minify) my JavaScript and CSS files dynamically in TYPO3?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using the scriptmerger extension. It automatizes this task for you.

Comment: why an extension, while TYPO3 provides inbuilt support for compression ??

Comment: Because some of those extensions are better (read: more effective, more features). Disclaimer: I contributed parts of the core implementation.

Answer (score 32):

You could use Typoscript (since 4.6):

```
config {
  concatenateJs = 1
  concatenateCss = 1

  compressJs = 1
  compressCss = 1
}

page {
  includeJS {
    myFile1 = fileadmin/js_file1.js

    myFile2 = fileadmin/js_file2.js
    myFile2.excludeFromConcatenation = 1
  }

  includeCSS {
    myFile1 = fileadmin/css_file1.css

    myFile2 = fileadmin/css_file2.css
    myFile2.disableCompression = 1
  }
}
```

See the [TSref documentation](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#concatenatejs)